# Extract ZIP in java

Tags: java, servlets, zip4j

Folks,

I am extracting the .zip files in java using **zip4j** API and able to extract the files

1. I have used to zip the complete Directory to make zip and it contains the files and nested directory, using

   zipFile.addFolder(fileDirectory, parameters);//ZIP directory files/folders
2. Extracting the zip using

   ```
   ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(stringArchievedFile);
   //Extracts all files to the path specified
   zipFile.extractAll(stringExtractingFilePath);
   ```

The problem is after the extraction, files should be extracted to the path I provided with the `zipFile.extractAll(path)` method but one more directory is being created. How can I extract the files to the actual specified directory

Like:
**Extracting Path**
C:\ExtractionPath

**Files Path**
C:\SelectingPath\File1

C:\SelectingPath\File2

C:\SelectingPath\Directory1\File1

C:\SelectingPath\Directory2\File1

I will select the **C:\SelectingPath** directory to zip and

I will select the **C:\ExtractionPath** directory to extract the files

after the extractions all the extracted files will be go into the

**C:\ExtractionPath\SelectingPath**

I need all the files in the directory in

**C:\ExtractionPath**
 itself.

Please help me to resolve this issues.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't zip the `SelectingPath` folder. Zip the content. If you open the zip file, you'll see that the path of all the files start with `SelectingPath`, and you don't want that.

Comment: You mean, I need to add all the files and directory to a `ArrayList` and pass it as an argument to  zipFile.addFiles() method as

`zipFile.addFiles(arrayListFilesFolders, parameters);` ?

Comment: @Andreas, If I use the ArrayList for both Files and Directories and pass it as an argument to zipFile.addFile() method, I am getting the below exceptions and can't able to archive the complete directory I choosen

`ex = (net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException) net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException: One or more elements in the input ArrayList is not of type File`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Andreas & esprittn!!

We need to pass the `ArrayList<File>` as the arguments to the `addFiles(ArrayList, ZipParameters)` method so that we can archive the entire directory contents of the directory. I got the output as expected

Follows the **ARCHIVE** code flow:

```
public void archieveFiles(File fileDirectory, String stringPassword) throws Exception {
        try{

            String[] filesDirectoryList = fileDirectory.list();

            ArrayList<File> listFileDirectory = new ArrayList<>(); //To list the files to archive
            for(int iListCount = 0; iListCount < filesDirectoryList.length; iListCount++){
                listFileDirectory.add(new File(fileDirectory+"\\"+filesDirectoryList[iListCount]));
            }

            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("C:\\CreateZIP\\FileArchive.zip");
            //Initiate Zip Parameters which define various properties
            ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters();
            // Set compression method to deflate compression
            parameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE); 
            parameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL); 
            //Set the encryption flag to true
            parameters.setEncryptFiles(true);
            //Set the encryption method to AES Zip Encryption
            parameters.setEncryptionMethod(Zip4jConstants.ENC_METHOD_AES);
            //file encrypted with key strength of 192, then Zip4j can decrypt this file
            parameters.setAesKeyStrength(Zip4jConstants.AES_STRENGTH_256);
            //Set password
            parameters.setPassword(stringPassword);
            // Zip the directory files
            zipFile.addFiles(listFileDirectory, parameters);
        }
        catch(ZipException ex){
            Logj.errorLog(ex);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Logj.errorLog(ex);
        }
    }
```

and the **EXTRACTION** is

```
public void extractFilesForFirmwareZip(String stringArchievedFile, String stringExtractingFilePath, String stringFileEncrypt) throws Exception{
        try{
            // Initiate ZipFile object with the path/name of the zip file.
            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(stringArchievedFile);
            //Initiate Zip Parameters which define various properties
            //UnzipParameters parameters = new UnzipParameters();
            if(zipFile.isEncrypted())
                zipFile.setPassword(stringFileEncrypt);
            //Extracts all files to the path specified
            zipFile.extractAll(stringExtractingFilePath);
        }
        catch(ZipException ex){
            isValidArchiveFile = false;
            Logj.doLog(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you try the examples from [Zip4j site](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/download.php)  like this one :

```
/*
* Copyright 2010 Srikanth Reddy Lingala  
* 
* Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); 
* you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. 
* You may obtain a copy of the License at 
* 
* http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 
* 
* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, 
* software distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, 
* WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. 
* See the License for the specific language governing permissions and 
* limitations under the License. 
*/

package net.lingala.zip4j.examples.extract;

import net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile;
import net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException;

/**
 * Demonstrates extracting all files from a zip file
 * 
 * @author Srikanth Reddy Lingala
 *
 */
public class ExtractAllFiles {

    public ExtractAllFiles() {

        try {
            // Initiate ZipFile object with the path/name of the zip file.
            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("c:\\ZipTest\\ExtractAllFiles.zip");

            // Extracts all files to the path specified
            zipFile.extractAll("c:\\ZipTest");

        } catch (ZipException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ExtractAllFiles();
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes. I used the example as well. But the problem I faced is same.